# Call function when a page link is opened

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to execute a Javascript function `myFunc(myParam)` automatically when a HTML link is opened, how can I achieve this without breaking compatibility with current browsers?

Notes:

- Function name is static whereas parameter is passed dynamically for each link.
- I've seen similar questions on SO but personally I would prefer not to use any JS library (if possible), but just my own code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a link like `<A href="mypage.html#myParam">`, then add this code to this page:

```
<BODY onLoad="pageLoaded();">
....
function pageLoaded() {
      var hash = window.location.hash;
      if (hash != "") {
             myFunc(hash);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very nicely with JQuery. I can't give you an extensive answer (on my mobile phone), but this should be enough to give it a go: [How do I run a jQuery function when any link (a) on my site is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538101/how-do-i-run-a-jquery-function-when-any-link-a-on-my-site-is-clicked)

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at this. Not sure to use jQuery at this time just for this, but if a second jQuery feature is useful for me, i may go for it :)